# Slow select performance on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am using SQL Server and I have a table like this one

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CompanyRolesExpanded (
  StaticId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
  UserId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  UserGroupId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  CompanyId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  CompanyGroupId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  CompanyAccessUnitRole uniqueidentifier NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (StaticId)
)
GO
```

For now, this table around 3 millions rows.
A simple select like this one takes around 30 seconds

```
SELECT  UserId,UserGroupId
       ,CompanyId,CompanyGroupId 
       ,CompanyAccessUnitRole                   
FROM CompanyRolesExpanded
```

Is there a way to improve it?

Comment: If you don't need to select the whole table, then use [`TOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Start with analyzing the execution plan.

Comment: Given that there are no joins and no predicates, is it possible that you just need a faster network connection or quicker disks? This feels more like a DBA question than a programming one. Where are you running the query? Are the results travelling over a network link of some kind? Do you really need to get all three million rows back?

Comment: All because of Unique-identifier, table fragmentation is too high. Using the NEWID or NEWSEQUENTIALID functions. Check your table fragmentation.

Comment: I just noticed that all of these columns are a `uniqueidentifier`, so the query, on it's own, isn't going to provide any meaningful information to anyone (I therefore find it hard to believe that this query is an example of the problem at hand). Also, having a Clustered Primary Key on a `uniqueidentifier` isn't actually a good idea: [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/). I'm beginning to think this is an xy question.

Comment: A query without a WHERE clause? Do you really need to retrieve all the 3 million?

Comment: It might be the client (maybe SSMS) that's taking long in showing the results rather than the server processing the request. Do a `SELECT INTO` and check if it takes a similar amount of time.

Comment: To add to @EzLo: The `GUID` is a binary pattern, but is displayed as a character string for human comsumers. 16 bytes in memory must be translated to a string of 32 meaningful characters plus some hyphens. 5 GUIDs in 3 million rows needs this to be done 15 mio times. Whatever you are doing here: This is not a relevant use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the full context of question ( like execution plan, indexes ) are unknown, I'm tempted to put down a rather large list of downfalls associated with GUIDs as my answer.

All column in your table have a GUID.

```
  StaticId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
  UserId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  UserGroupId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  CompanyId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  CompanyGroupId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  CompanyAccessUnitRole uniqueidentifier NULL
```

To quote the cons from a [source](https://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/) where author favors GUIDs

> **GUID Cons**
>
> 1. It is a whopping 4 times larger than the traditional 4-byte index value; this can have serious performance and storage implications if
>      you're not careful
> 2. Cumbersome to debug where userid='{BAE7DF4-DDF-3RG-5TY3E3RF456AS10}'
> 3. The generated GUIDs should be partially sequential for best performance (eg, newsequentialid() on SQL 2005) and to enable use of
>      clustered indexes

Your data will be spread across more pages and will have more physical reads compared to using say int for Key.

If you do many number of inserts/updates/deletes, your indexes will be highly fragmented. This is so because the GUIDs are generated at random and it takes a toll at engine to update index for organizing them in a sequential order.

My bet is that your indexes need to be rebuilt. Here's **[an article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5105/sql-server-performance-comparison-int-versus-guid/)** which compares GUID with INT column indexes and reflects that GUID is slower than INT but can be improved and brought at par on index rebuilding.

If you think that GUID are the culprit, I'd suggest that you should look at `bigint` as an option

Comment: that was my assumption as well, that the Guids are to blame, but I cannot get rid of them. I am investigation a performance problem and I have created this table (instead of running different join and selects at runtime) to see how it behaves.

Comment: The OP can use `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`, which fixes some of the problems (actually the more important ones).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think guids are the long pole in the tent from a performance perspective in this case. Running the PowerShell test below of a 3M row select from a remote server, the results showed the int test is about 10% faster on average. Assuming similar results in your environment, that would translate to 27 seconds with int versus 30 with guid. I observed most of the time was due to client CPU processing of the large result set.

This isn't to say there aren't considerations with guids, especially on a single-disk spinning media storage, but I wanted to make it clear that it's the large result set that is the issue rather than the data type.

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=PerformanceTestScript";

$guidSetupScript = @"
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example (
  StaticId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
  UserId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  UserGroupId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  CompanyId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  CompanyGroupId uniqueidentifier NULL,
  CompanyAccessUnitRole uniqueidentifier NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (StaticId)
);
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1k AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
    ,t10m AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num FROM t1k AS a CROSS JOIN t1k AS b CROSS JOIN t1k AS c CROSS JOIN t10 AS d)
INSERT INTO dbo.Example WITH(TABLOCKX) (
      StaticId
    , UserId
    , UserGroupId
    , CompanyId
    , CompanyGroupId
    , CompanyAccessUnitRole
    )
SELECT
      NEWID()
    , NEWID()
    , NEWID()
    , NEWID()
    , NEWID()
    , NEWID()
FROM t10m
WHERE num <= 3000000;
"@

$intSetupScript = @"
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example (
  StaticId int NOT NULL,
  UserId int NULL,
  UserGroupId int NULL,
  CompanyId int NULL,
  CompanyGroupId int NULL,
  CompanyAccessUnitRole int NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (StaticId)
);
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1k AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
    ,t10m AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num FROM t1k AS a CROSS JOIN t1k AS b CROSS JOIN t1k AS c CROSS JOIN t10 AS d)
INSERT INTO dbo.Example WITH(TABLOCKX) (
      StaticId
    , UserId
    , UserGroupId
    , CompanyId
    , CompanyGroupId
    , CompanyAccessUnitRole
    )
SELECT
      num
    , num
    , num
    , num
    , num
    , num
FROM t10m
WHERE num <= 3000000;
"@

try
{
    $values = [System.Array]::CreateInstance([System.Object], 6)
    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $command.CommandTimeout = 0
    $connection.Open()
    $command.Connection = $connection

    #Guid setup
    $command.CommandText = "IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Example') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Example;"
    [void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $command.CommandText = $guidSetupScript
    [void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    #guid test
    $testSw = [System.Diagnostics.StopWatch]::StartNew()
    Write-Host "Starting Guid test."
    $command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Example;"
    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
    while($reader.Read()) {
        $values = $reader.GetValues($values)
    }
    $reader.Close()
    $testSw.Stop()
    Write-Host "Guid test duration was $($testSw.Elapsed.ToString())"

    #int setup
    $command.CommandText = "IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Example') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Example;"
    [void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $command.CommandText = $intSetupScript
    [void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    #int test
    $testSw = [System.Diagnostics.StopWatch]::StartNew()
    Write-Host "Starting int test."
    $command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Example;"
    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
    while($reader.Read()) {
        $values = $reader.GetValues($values)
    }
    $reader.Close()
    $testSw.Stop()
    Write-Host "Int test duration was $($testSw.Elapsed.ToString())"

    $connedtion.Close()

}
catch [Exception]
{
    throw
}
```